# Chrome not recognizing CORS headers

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, cors

I have ASP.NET application (.NET framework 4.5), I've added those lines in the web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE"/>
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

However, when I run it (on localhost) and trying to access it using AJAX from another host, chrome complains about `Method Not Allowed`. Removing those lines will make it complain about the Origin, so that means it does recognize the Allow-Origin header properly, however it doesn't seem to recognize the Allow-Methods for some reason.

I did check the developer tools network tab and I can clearly see the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header, which makes absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743

Comment: @WiktorZychla the link talks about problem with Allow-Origin, while in my case it works just fine, my problem is with Allow-Method.

Comment: The link mentions various issues with `localhost`. One of the further linked entries, http://williambert.online/2013/06/allow-cors-with-localhost-in-chrome/ claims you also need `Allow-Headers` header. The solution is dated 2013 though, just check if it's still valid.

Comment: What’s the exact error message you’re getting about “Method Not Allowed”? What’s the exact HTTP status code you’re getting in the response from the server? If your server is sending a 405 status code in the response, then that has nothing to do with the Access-Control-Allow-\* headers you’re setting but instead only has to do with your server not allowing OPTIONS requests at all.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I'm off work for couple days so can't get the exact error message, but far as I remember the status code was 405 indeed, however the server did accept the OPTIONS request, because in my ASP.NET application I've added a method to handle OPTIONS requests and set a breakpoint and verified it worked, but the breakpoint in GET handler didn't invoke, in chrome the network tab showed 2 requests: OPTIONS did get a 200 OK response, but the GET got a 405 response.